# How do I get accurev to find a moved workspace?

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

I created a workspace in AccuRev under M:\EclipseWorkspaces\. 
The project checked out fine.

Then I moved the project to C:\EclipseWorkspaces\.
Now AccuRev thinks the project does not exists. This is probably because AccuRev is looking for the project on my M drive.

How do I get AccuRev to find my project?

I am using version 5.3.
This computer is slow so I'd like to do this using the CLI.

Update: I deleted the workspace in the AccuRev client.... Can I add the workspace on my C drive into my stream in AccuRev?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, So I deleted the workspace in the stream (in AccuRev client)... or so I thought.
AccuRev does not actually remove the workspace; AccuRev deactivates the workspace.

So first I had to reactivate it (using CLI):

```
accurev reactivate wspace foo_workspace
```

Then I had to change the location of the workspace in accurev

```
C:\EclipseWorkspace>accurev chws -w foo_workspace -l .
```

Notes: 
-w is the name of your workspace (must be yours, can't be someone else's; there is -s for that) 
-l is the location you want to change the physical location too

Comment: Worked like a charm. Probably obvious, but be sure you restart the UI if it was running during the location change.

Answer (score 5):

thischangeYou should Reactivate the workspace from the client GUI, use Show Hidden checkbox in the stream browser to do so.  Then, the cli command you'll use is:

accurev chws -w wspace-name -l C:\EclipseWorkspaces\

That will assign the workspace location as AccuRev knows it to the new, correct location...

Update: you will need to close and reopen the gui for it to recognize this change...